# Print an upside down triangle recursively

Tags: java, recursion, ascii-art

I am trying to figure out how to print an upside-down triangle recursively, using only one for-loop. I keep getting an error. I'm able to print the first row but I'm having a hard time recalling the function to print the remaining rows and decrementing n.

```
    public static void printTriangle (int n) {
        if( n == 0 ) 
            System.out.println("");
        for (int i = n; i >0; i--) {
            System.out.print("*");    
        }
        System.out.println();
        printTriangle(n-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, when you should end the recursion at your base case you don't. Basically, change

```
if( n == 0 ) 
    System.out.println("");
```

to

```
if (n == 0) {
    System.out.println();
    return; // Add this. Otherwise your code will recurse forever.
}
```